# Fix row without adding the box size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Need help here
Is there a way to fix size of a box in body without growing more than the body itself ?

Here's the body :
[image]

When table 1 have more record it will add the height of the box while the range between table 1 and table 2 is the same.
[image]

What i need:
When table 1 have more record it will not add height of the box and consume the range between tb1 and tb2 until it's completely no more space then it will go to next page.
Is there a way to reach this ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some quick help:

Add a Rectangle (Rec1) with the top at the top of Table1 (T1) and ends at Table 2 (T2).

Put T1 in it.

When T1 grows, it will consume space in rectangle and NOT push down T2 AS LONG AS you limit T1 records to fit in Rec1.

You'll need to add a ROW_NUMBER to the SQL data.

Figure out how many records can fit and filter the table for that many by ROW_NUM (ROW_NUM <= 20).

Copy T1 and make T3 with ROW_NUM > 20.